# Equivalent circuit of spiral resonator metamaterial

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, transmission-line

I require equivalent circuit for two sided square spiral resonator for metamaterials.

I have found the equivalent circuit for one side, according to this paper:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3132118_Equivalent-Circuit_Models_for_the_Design_of_Metamaterials_Based_on_Artificial_Magnetic_Inclusions

[image: spiral resonator]

I found a design which connects two layer mirrored spirals through a vias. Is the equivalent circuit therefore the circuit in series or the total length and turns from both sides should be combined to calculate the parameters.

Two sided diagram
[image: two sided design]

I shall provide additional information to the question if required as I am unsure.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define the results you want to measure

Comment: http://smirc.stanford.edu/papers/JSSC99OCT-mohan.pdf